# Google APIs to manage policies to block/restrict add-in(s) in google/Gsuite

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a requirement to block/restrict specific add-ins for user(s) in accessing. I could able to block add-ins using google admin portal ( Security -> API Control), which solves the problem but instead of doing this manually, I would like to automate the same using google APIs. I tried to explore users, tokens, etc APIs but could not find an option. Appreciate if you can suggest an option to achieve this functionality through API.

Comment: Add your additional comments to the first question,

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. I added more details in the first question